# Update Chrome version in puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, version, puppeteer

i tryed to use puppeteer for Youtube, but I´m getting a message that my browser is to old to see videos - any idea?

@Benjamins-MBP Intagram_bot-master % node YViews.js
Chrome/78.0.3882.0

Comment: Try to update your puppeteer version, the last puppeteer version is usually shipped with the last Chrome version.

Comment: just did this - Chrome/78.0.3882.0

Comment: As you can see at the top of the doc page, the last 9.0 puppeteer version uses Chrome 91: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md Do you use Chrome shipped with puppeteer or installed differently in the system?